# Importing an excel (xls) file into javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, import-from-excel

I would like to import an excel file into javascript. 
I already have got a code that works (kind of). 
This is my code:

```
 function GetData(cell,row){
   var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
   var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("U:\\File1.xls");
   var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
   var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
   return data;

   }
```

The code only works in IE (because of ActiveX), and it is incredibly slow.
Another problem is that it can only get the data from the first 100 rows or so, after that it just loads for hours and I get an ObjectError.

Another way to import excel files, or something that works the same way, would be greatly appreciated.

Updated Code:
Opens the file just once. But now i get an Object Error inside of the try-catch, when i try to run the GetData(i,2) method.

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("U:\\Datei.xls");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet 1");

function GetData(cell,row){
   var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell,row).Value;
   return data;

   }

function main(){                         

            try{        
            for(var i=1; i<5000;i++){
                if(text1 == GetData(i,2)){
                    alert(GetData(i,6));
                    throw "Entry found";

                 }
                }
            }
catch(e) {
     alert(e)
   }
    }
```

Comment: please post details for error ObjectError. thanks

Comment: You're launching Excel and loading a file to get each cell value - of course that's going to be slow.  Open the file once, and read all the values you need.

Comment: @Tim Williams Oh yes, how could i not think of that. I will try to open it just once and post here again in a few minutes.

Comment: You have a misprint in your code `alert(GetData(i,6);` add one more `)`

Comment: Fixed that, but that did not cause the problem.

Comment: Seems like the program is not able to open excel file in the first three lines